# Как использовать reachGoal яндекс метрики в связке с реакт

Tags: reactjs, form, yandex-metrika-api

Такой вопрос, в справке яндекс метрики указываются варианты подключения целей в общих чертах, в основном с использованием ванильного js или jQuery, соответственно такой вопрос как использовать ее в связке с реакт если есть отдельный компонент с отправкой формы, как инициализировать ym функцию в оном и с условием, что счетчик подсчитывает только успешные отправки

Пробовал использовать библиотеку react-yandex-metrika, но проблема в том, что дебагер показывает инициализацию PageView, но счетчик после отправки формы не улетает, если смотреть через консоль